# Как проверить с помощью кода, включён ли канал на твиче?

Tags: php, потоки-данных, функции, streaming

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть массив **matches**, там в графе **english** - я ввожу ник стримера, к примеру **dreamhackcs**. Далее моя функция подключается к БД и берет значение из колонки **english**. Ссылка на видео выглядит так:

```
<iframe src="//player.twitch.tv/?channel=<?=$match['english']?>&autoplay=false" height="480" width="832" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen=""/>
```

Собственно говоря как проверить с помощью функции что этот канал активен? и если нет, то идёт переход к следующей трансляции: с графой russian и тд